# Как создать батник с командой netsh wlan start hostednetwork?

Tags: bat

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать батник с командой  `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` , чтобы каждый раз включая компьютер мне не приходилось залазить в командную строку и вводить это вручную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаешь текстовый файл, вносишь в него свою строку кода:

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Затем переименовываешь файл в *.bat
И просто запускаешь, когда это необходимо.

Comment: И добавить в Пуск -> все программы -> Автозагрузка.

Comment: @Света Света просто bat файл то запускается?

Comment: Спасибо!) всё вышло!)

Comment: @Света Света не забывайте отмечать правильный ответ! Спасибо!